# how to re-use existing completion with recent bash-completion?

Tags: bash, debian, autocomplete

i use *alias* which adds some parameters to some program.

for example:

```
alias git.home='git --git-dir=$HOME/.git.home/'

complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _git git.home \
  2>/dev/null || complete -o default -o nospace -F _git git.home
```

it works with `bash-completion v.1:2.0-1` ("debian 7 wheezy"):
<kbd>tab</kbd> completes parameters and options for *alias* `git.home` as well as for "original" `git`.

but with `bash-completion v.1:2.1-4` ("debian 8 jessie") after typing `git.home` and pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> i get this error:

> bash: completion: function `_git' not found

how to re-use existing completion (for example for `git`) with recent versions of package `bash-completion`?

---

**update**

found partial solution: do `source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git` before `complete ...`

but i get another error - `git.home log` + <kbd>space</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> results in:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
>   HEAD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**updated**

solution for *alias* `git.home`, which operates with `~/.git.home` as repo.

partially based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216899/110559).

add to `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias git.home='git --git-dir=$HOME/.git.home/'

_completion_loader git
eval "$(complete -p git | sed -r 's/(\s)git$/\1git.home/')"

eval "$(type __gitdir | 
  sed '1d;1,/if/s|if|if [[ "$COMP_LINE" == "git.home "* ]]; then\necho "$HOME/.git.home"\nelif|')"
```

---

**explanation of last `eval`** (for other lines see [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216899/110559)):

we are patching the function `__gitdir()`, which returns a path to the git repo dir. from:

```
$ type __gitdir | head -n 4
__gitdir is a function
__gitdir () 
{ 
    if [ -z "${1-}" ]; then
```

to:

```
$ type __gitdir | head -n 7
__gitdir is a function
__gitdir () 
{ 
    if [[ "$COMP_LINE" == "git.home "* ]]; then
        echo "$HOME/.git.home";
    else
        if [ -z "${1-}" ]; then
```

i.e., if command starts with a `"git.home "`, function returns `$HOME/.git.home`.

Answer (score 8):

> how to re-use existing completion (for example for git) with recent versions of package bash-completion

Add the following lines to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
_completion_loader git
eval $(complete -p git | perl -pe 's/(\s)git$/$1git.home/')
```

**Explanation:**

`bash-completion` uses a dynamic loading of completions since [1.90](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/bash-completion/blob/9176828dd0997c8be39e31c312acc661eda08fcb/CHANGES). So, the `git` compspec unavailable before your typing `git`,<kbd>Space</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Try:

```
bash
complete -p git # bash: complete: git: no completion specification
git<space><tab>
complete -p git # complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F __git_wrap__git_main git
```

`_completion_loader git` imitates `git`,<kbd>Space</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd> (i.e. loads a compspec for `git`)

`complete -p git | perl -pe 's/(\s)git$/$1git.home/'` builds a compspec for `git.home` (replaces `git` to `git.home` in a `git`'s compspec)

`eval` execute the resulting compspec.

Type `git.home`,<kbd>Space</kbd>,`p`<kbd>Tab</kbd>. You should see:

```
popt   pull   push
```

**But** `git.home log`,<kbd>Space</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd> produces:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git HEAD

This message is a result of the git completion bug. There is a fix in the upstream: [completion: silence "fatal: Not a git repository" error](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f7ff5b2fe7f52966c034a12cf8980dae1160222)

<del>Looks like another question:)</del>

```
_githome(){ 
   GIT_DIR=$HOME/.git.home
   complete -o default -o nospace -F _git git.home
 }
```

doesn't work as expected. You set `GIT_DIR` for current session. Try with your solution:

```
bash
git clone git://git.debian.org/git/bash-completion/bash-completion.git ~/bash-completion
cd ~/bash-completion
git log<space><tab> # completion for current repo
git.home log<space><tab> # completion for GIT_DIR
git log<space><tab> # completion for GIT_DIR
```

Comment: *doesn't work as expected* — it works for me as expected. f.e., `git log` shows history for the repo in `./.git/`, and `git.home log ` shows history for the repo in `~/.git.home/`. and completion of *branches* in both cases is working correctly.

Comment: hm, I can't reproduce. What do you see after last `git log<space><tab>`?  What do you see for `git --git-dir=.git log<space><tab>` in `~/bash_completion`?

Comment: 1. use *jessie* and "official" package *bash-completion*. 2. append [these lines](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216806/110559) to `~/.bashrc` and re-login. 3. `cp -a /some/repo/.git ~/.git.home`. 4. `cd`. 5. try `git.home log`, `git.home status` etc.

Comment: *What do you see after last git log<space><tab>* — hmm. in home dir this should cause the error, but i see branches from `~/.git.home`

Comment: yes, `cd`, `git.home log`, `git.home status` works fine. but `git log<space><tab>` always shows `git --git-dir=$HOME/.git.home for-each-ref '--format=%(refname:short)' refs/tags refs/heads refs/remotes` and `HEAD`. i.e. `git.home` completion affects `git` completion

Comment: *Looks like another question* — not [anymore](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216806/110559).

Comment: cool! I updated my answer: added info about git completion bug: [completion: silence "fatal: Not a git repository" error](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f7ff5b2fe7f52966c034a12cf8980dae1160222)

Comment: a! realized. but, in my opinion, an error message *per se*  is **not** a bug.

Comment: yes, you are right. Unknown `git-dir` in `git.home` completion was a real bug

Answer (score 0):

This is a general answer that should work for any completion function. I'm concerned about the insecurity of the other answers assuming a single line output to be parsed by `sed` or `perl` and I can implement that without an external call.

```bash
# Usage: complete_as TARGET COMMAND [COMMAND...]
# Tab-complete one or more COMMANDs like TARGET
complete_as() {
  _completion_loader "$1"
  local completion="$(complete -p "$1")"
  completion="${completion%[[:space:]]$1}"
  shift
  eval "$completion $@"
}
complete_as git git.home
```

Just like the `sed` and `perl` code in the older answers, this replaces the last instance of the target command (`$1`) with the new command (`$2`), but I'm using [parameter substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#from_the_end), which views the whole content rather than running on each line of the output. This is important because the end of the output of the completion function sometimes has line breaks (as is the case with `complete -W "$(_parse_help foo)" foo`). Removing external calls also makes this much faster, which you may notice if you're doing a lot of these.

You could similarly build such safeties (and use bash substitution) to fix the `__gitdir` function like [aleksandr barakin's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216806/87770) does.

See also [this zsh solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496759/87770) to the same question.