# Treat command like another for completion purposes

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

My zshrc includes the following function to create a directory and then enter it:

```
function mcd () {
    mkdir -p "$*" && cd "$*"
}
```

The function itself works fine but I get odd behavior with completion. If I start typing e.g. `mcd ~/` and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the message

```
_mtools_drives:3: command not found: mtoolstest
```

is inserted at the insertion point and nothing is completed. What I want is for the command to be completed just as `mkdir` would be: zsh should offer me the names of existing directories.

How do I tell zsh that for completion purposes, it should treat `mcd` the same as `mkdir`?

Comment: While that doesn't solve your problem, you can use `take <directory_name>` to achieve the same behaviour as your `mcd` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following snippet causes `mcd` to be completed like `mkdir`:

```
compdefas () {
  if (($+_comps[$1])); then
    compdef $_comps[$1] ${^@[2,-1]}=$1
  fi
}
compdefas mkdir mcd
```

The way it works is to look up the current completion setting for `mkdir`. The completion code for a function (generally the name of a completion function) is stored in the associative array `_comps`. Thus `compdef $_comps[mkdir] mcd` declares that `mcd` should be completed in the same way that `mkdir` is completed right now.

The function above adds a few niceties:

- The test for `(($+_comps[$1]))` ensures that if `$1` doesn't have a specified completion method then no completion method is set for the other arguments.
- `${@[2,-1]}` is the list of arguments to the function starting with the second one, so you can specify more than one command name to define completions for. It's actually `${^@[a,-1]}` so that [the text around the array expansion is replicated for each array element](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-RCEXPANDPARAM).
- `=$1` sets the [service name to use](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-compdef). This matters only for a few commands whose completion function handles several closely-related commands. For example the completion function `_gzip` handles both `gzip` and `gunzip` as well as `pigz` and `unpigz`; `compdef _gzip foo` makes `foo` use the default behavior of `_gzip` while `compdef _gzip foo=pigz` makes `foo` use the behavior of `_gzip` when it completes for `pigz`.

---

Turning to your specific case, the default completion for `mkdir` not only offers directories, but also options, which your function does not support. So you'd actually be better off defining `mcd` as just completing existing directories. Zsh comes with a helper function for that (an undocumented wrapper around [`_files`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005ffiles)).

```
compdef _directories mcd
```

The reason you were getting these bizarre-looking completions for `mcd` is that it's the name of a command from a once moderately widespread suite of commands [mtools](https://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/).

Comment: If I issue command `mcd` without any argument, then it echos `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory`. `mkdir` will give `mkdir: missing operand` which look nicer than our `mcd`, how to have the same behavior as `mkdir`?

Comment: @TuyenPham See if [my function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9123/is-there-a-one-liner-that-allows-me-to-create-a-directory-and-move-into-it-at-th/9124#9124) inspires you.

Comment: Thanks, that's truly mkdir wrapper, but should we still need to have `compdefas`? As I test your `mkcd` function, it works well with completion.

Comment: Should this have double-quotes around things, and if so, where?

Comment: @Adam In zsh, you don't need double quotes around `$foo` if the resulting word is not empty. `compdefas mkdir mcd` is equivalent to `compdef _mkdir mcd` with the advantage of working with commands that don't obey the completion function naming convention of pretending an underscore.

Answer (score 5):

`compdef` uses the following form:

```
compdef [ -ane ] function name
```

so one idea would be to point the `name` of `mcd` at the `_mkdir` function via the following command:

```
compdef _mkdir mcd
```

however this is slightly incorrect as `mkdir` completes various flags that should probably not also be given to `cd`. More direct would be to complete on directories:

```
compdef _directories mcd
```